# Is it possible to switch between disconnected in user sessions in CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, gnome

I have a CentOS 7 Virtual Machine that I access using xRDP (through a Guacamole server) from a Windows machine.

Occasionally my xRDP session will timeout and I'll be disconnected. When I re-connect to my VM and login again, I'll be present with a fresh new desktop, even if I had open applications prior to being disconnected. I can see using `ps -ef` that those applications are still running.

If — for example — I attempt to open Firefox again then it'll come back with an error stating that it is already open and needs to be closed first.

I have to `pkill firefox` before I can open it. I can also see that I have multiple instances of my user account (dcgsadmin) logged in. The command `who` displays the following output:

```
dcgsadmin pts/0    2020-08-05 09:10 (:10.0)
dcgsadmin pts/1    2020-08-05 09:12 (:10.0)
dcgsadmin pts/2    2020-08-05 09:30 (:11.0)
```

So the question then is how do I switch back to my previously logged in session? Is this possible? Is there a way to switch between `pts sessions` or `screens`? Is this a feature of gnome?